# Dispatch action with observable as payload

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an Angular application that utilizes `ngrx/store` to maintain application state.

In my root component, I want to dispatch an action to set the visibility of a sidebar in the state. At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'ye';
  isSidenavVisible$: Observable<boolean>;
  private isSidenavVisible: boolean; // Is this really needed?

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.isSidenavVisible$ = this.store.select(getIsSidenavVisible);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isSidenavVisible$.subscribe(isSidenavVisible => {
      this.isSidenavVisible = isSidenavVisible;
    });
  }

  toggleSidenav() {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetSidenavVisibility(!this.isSidenavVisible));
    // I would like to dispatch the observable as a payload instead
  }
}
```

Even though this works, I would like to get rid of the (in my opinion) superfluous `private isSidenavVisible` variable, ending up with being able to work with the only the observable of `isSidenavVisible$`.

The initial state is set to `true` in the reducer.

Is this possibly, and if so, in what way could I simplify my code even further?

Comment: If rather then using Observable if you use BehaviourSubject as the type of isSidenavVisible$ then you can do something like isSidenavVisible$.getValue()
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md

Comment: `BehaviourSubject` looks interesting, thanks for the link!

Comment: Let me know if it works with ngrx store.

Comment: I'm quite sure that would work, but it'd mean a rewrite of some other things that I don't want to do. Instead, I'll go with `this.isSidenavVisible$.first().subscribe(isVisible => {
      this.store.dispatch(new SetSidenavVisibility(!isVisible));
    });` which will fetch the value and unsubscribe automatically. It resolves my desire to get rid of the superfluous private variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going with the alternative `BehaviourSubject` method, I chose to subscribe temporarily to the observable inside the `toggleSidenav()` function.

```
toggleSidenav() {
  this.isSidenavHidden$.first().subscribe(isVisible => {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetSidenavVisibility(!isVisible));
  });
}
```

The result is as desired, no need for a private value variable, and since I use `.first()` the subscription will be unsubscribed to automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Bind observable in the to sidebar template with `async` pipe

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'ye';
  isSidenavVisible$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.isSidenavVisible$ = this.store.select(getIsSidenavVisible);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    /* This is not needed because the default value is set in the reducer
    this.isSidenavVisible$.subscribe(isSidenavVisible => {
        this.isSidenavVisible = isSidenavVisible;
    }); */
  }

  toggleSidenav() {
    this.store.dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_NAVBAR'}); //The logic used to toggle the sidenav is in the reducer
  }
}
```

And in your template something like this

```html
<div *ngIf="isSidenavVisible$ | async">my content to hide</div>
```

You must use the [reducers](https://youtu.be/pjwVq8B-ZAw?t=26m25s)

The toogle code can be something like this:

```js
export const toggleReducer = (state = false, {type, payload}) => { //state = false is the initial condition
  switch(type){
    case TOGGLE_NAVBAR:
      return !state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bijdKgX8oiW71AaBjwCy) is the plunker if you want to see a working example

Answer (score 0):

couldnt you just bind observable directly to sidebar visibility through `async` pipe and resolve it directly in template?